# Structure an associative array for json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am trying to create an associative array within a function. The function extracts information from a website. What I am having trouble doing is creating json which would output:

```
[{
  Cardiology_STEMI : [ 
     {name: Dr. John},
     {service name: Cardiology STEMI}
     {office: 973-111-1111},
     {shift: 7a-7p},
     {cell : 973-222-2222}]
}
{ Pulmonary : [
     {name: Dr.Bob},
     {office: (123)456-789},
     {service_name: Pulmonary},
     {shift: 7a-7p},
     {cell: (123)456-789}
}]
   [...and so on (x 30 entries])
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to get the service name to show up outside the main array so that it becomes an associative array. When I try to modify the data output, it never comes out right.

```
<!--Example of what the page looks like 

<td class = "Cardiology specialty"> Cardiology STEMI </td>
<td class = "Cardiology specialty name"> Dr. John </td>
<td class = "Cardiology specialty shift"> 7a-7p </td>
<td class = "Cardiology specialty office"> (973)-111-1111 </td>
<td class = "Cardiology specialty cell"> (973)-222-2222 </td>

<td class = "Pulmonary specialty"> Pulmonary </td>
<td class = "Pulmonary specialty name"> Dr. Bob </td>
<td class = "Pulmonary specialty shift"> 7a-7p </td>
<td class = "Pulmonary specialty office"> (123)456-7890 </td>
<td class = "Pulmonary specialty cell"> (123)456-7890 </td>
-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var providers = []
var cardiology = data("Cardiology");
          providers.push(cardiology);

var pulmonary = data("Pulmonary");
          providers.push(pulmonary);

var json = JSON.stringify(providers);
sendData(json);


   function data(specialty){
     var service = $("."+specialty+".service:lt(1)").text().trim().replace(/\s/g,"_");
     var service_name = $("."+specialty+".service:lt(1)").text();
     var name = $("."+specialty+".name:lt(1)").text();
     var shift = $("."+specialty+".shift:lt(1)").text();
     var office = $("."+specialty+".office:lt(1)").text();
     var cell = $("."+specialty+".cell:lt(1)").text();

        var data = {
           service: service_name, 
           name: name, 
           shift: shift, 
           office: office, 
           cell: cell};

    return data
   }; 

function sendData(data){
    $.post('https://www.empa.app/api/submit_providers',    
       { providers: data },                               
       function(data, status, jqXHR) {                  
                $('p').append('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + data);
        })
     }
})
</script>
```

Can anyone help guide me to where I may be missing something essential, or doing something wrong?

Comment: javascript doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: I'm looking for an easy way to later retrieve information from JSON, however it seems difficult to retrieve it (lets say in handlebars) if it's only a number in an array rather than easily typing something like "cardiology.name". Is there another way if associative arrays aren't something feasable?

Comment: javascript has objects (with key value pairs), and arrays (with indexes).  The statement that javascript does not have associative arrays simply means there is not a native element that allows you to reference the same contained value by an id and by an index.

Answer (score 0):

If for "associative array" you mean "a structure allowing data to be stored as `key: value` pairs", yes we do have that. In JS we have `Object`.

There are different ways to create such structures, the most common way (also, **the** way preferred and recommended by JS developers) is through the object literal `{}`.
Data contained in such structures can be accessed in different ways; the intended way is the dot-notation `obj.key`, but the array-like accessor `obj["key"]` is equivalent:

```
var planet = {
    name: "Earth",
    greeting: "Hello, world!"
};

console.log("Planet", planet.name, "says:", planet["greeting"]);
// Planet Earth says: Hello, world!
```

Fun fact: `Array`s in JS are a special type of `Object` where each `key` is an integer. I won't go into details here though, instead, I'd highly recommend looking up the [Mozilla developer JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) to learn more about the fundamental structures of JS.

As for your original issue, you could create a structure like this:

```
var list = {
    Cardiology_STEMI: {
        "Dr. John": {
            office: "973-111-1111",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "973-222-2222"
        },
        "Dr. Mike": {
            office: "973-333-3333",
            shift: "4a-4p",
            cell: "973-444-4444"
        },
        "Dr. Paul": {
            office: "973-555-5555",
            shift: "4a-4p",
            cell: "973-666-6666"
        }
    },
    Pulmonary: {
        "Dr. Bob": {
            office: "(123)456-789",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "(123)456-789"
        },
        "Dr. Bruce":{
            office: "(987)654-321",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "(987)654-321"
        },
        "Dr. Banner":{
            office: "(999)888-777",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "(999)888-777"
        }
    }
};
```

And then, retrieving data for a specific doctor using the array-like accessor:

```
var DrMike = list.Cardiology_STEMI["Dr. Mike"];
var DrBanner = list.Pulmonary["Dr. Banner"];

console.log(DrMike, DrBanner);
// {name: "Dr. Mike", office: "973-333-3333", shift: "4a-4p", cell: "973-444-4444"}
// {name: "Dr. Banner", office: "(999)888-777", shift: "7a-7p", cell: "(999)888-777"}
```

Alternatively, an actual array would be more beneficial once you get more familiar with the `filter()`, `map()`, `find()` (and other) methods of Array objects:

```
var list = {
    Cardiology_STEMI: [
        {
            name: "Dr. John",
            office: "973-111-1111",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "973-222-2222",
        },{
            name: "Dr. Mike",
            office: "973-333-3333",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "973-444-4444",
        },{
            name: "Dr. Paul",
            office: "973-555-5555",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "973-666-6666",
        }
    ],
    Pulmonary: [
        {
            name: "Dr. Bob",
            office: "(123)456-789",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "(123)456-789",
        },{
            name: "Dr. Bruce",
            office: "(987)654-321",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "(987)654-321",
        },{
            name: "Dr. Banner",
            office: "(999)888-777",
            shift: "7a-7p",
            cell: "(999)888-777",
        }
    ]
};
```

To find a specific doctor in a specific category:

```
var DrMike = list.Cardiology_STEMI.find(drDetails=>{
    return (drDetails.name === "Dr. Mike");
});
console.log(DrMike);
// {name: "Dr. Mike", office: "973-333-3333", shift: "4a-4p", cell: "973-444-4444"}

var DrBanner = list.Cardiology_STEMI.find(drDetails=>{
    return (drDetails.name === "Dr. Banner");
});
console.log(DrBanner);
// {name: "Dr. Banner", office: "(999)888-777", shift: "7a-7p", cell: "(999)888-777"}
```

To find cardiology_STEMI doctors available between 4AM and 4PM:

```
var cardiology_STEMI_avail_4AM_4PM = list.Cardiology_STEMI.filter(drDetails => {
    return (drDetails.shift === "4a-4p");
});

console.log(cardiology_STEMI_avail_4AM_4PM);
// [
//  {name: "Dr. Mike", office: "973-333-3333", shift: "4a-4p", cell: "973-444-4444"}
//  {name: "Dr. Paul", office: "973-555-5555", shift: "4a-4p", cell: "973-666-6666"}
// ]
```

Hopefully this will be of help :)

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you for the in depth answer and will benefit me greatly! However one question. When constructing var list (in your example), I'm unsure how to actually create it within a function. How would you go about creating a function which returns your example (var list, as an actual array)?

Comment: It depends on how the remote API (website) will return the data in the first place. In general you'll have a function that calls the website API, maybe it returns the data maybe in a structure similar to the `var list` above, so you can just use it as-is. If the structure returned by the API is not convenient, you can always transform it into something more convenient for your use case. If you could provide more details on where the remote API comes from or anything else, I may be able to help you further.